# How to convert Word2VecKeyedVectors to FastText or Word2Vec object in Gensim?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

The following command will load a word2vec format file into a KeyedVectors object:

```
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("w2v_model.bin", binary=True)
```

My question is how to convert this KeyedVectors object into gensim.models.fasttext.FastText or gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec object.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a reason to do that: A `Word2Vec` / `FastText` model should be used just in case you want to **continue training**, which is not possible anyway ([see gensim docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format)).

All other use cases should be possible (and faster) to be done using `KeyedVectors`.